# Let $X$ be a random variable with continuous CDF $F$. Find CDF for $|X|$ and (if $F\in C^1$) density $f_{|X|}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with continuous distribution function $F$.

1. Find the distribution function $F_{|X|}$ for $|X|$.
2. Suppose that $F\in C^1$ . Find the density for $|X|$.

My approach was like this:
$$ F_{|X|}(x) = P(|X|\leq x) = P(-x \leq X \leq x) = F(x)-\lim_{y\uparrow-x}F(-x) = F(x)-F(-x) $$
In the last step I used the fact that $F$ is continuous.

Now the problem is the second part, I'm a little confused. Suppose that $F\in C^1$. Define $f:=F'$. It follows that $f_{|X|}(x):=F_{|X|}'(x) = F'(x) - F'(-x) = f(x) + f(-x)$. I know that $f$ is the density from $X$, but $f_{|X|}$ should be the density from |X| right? I'm probably making a mistake here somewhere but I think $f_{|X|}$ isn't a pdf because
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{|X|}(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) + f(-x)\,dx = 
$$
$$
=\underset{=1}{\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx}}
+ \underset{\neq 0}{\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(-x)\,dx}} \neq 1
$$

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: But |X| takes values only in $[0,+\infty)$ not in $(-\infty, +\infty)$. So, the formula you got for $F$ is for $x>0$ and respectively you should define the integration limits in the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|X| \in [0, +\infty)$ you should be aware that the formula you got for $F$ is valid only for $x\ge0$. Thus in the second part you have that $$\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{|X|}(x)dx&=\int_{-\infty}^{0}0dx+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(f(x)-f(-x)\right)dx\\&=0+\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(-x)dx\\&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1\end{align*}$$

Comment: Oh, I should have seen that. Thanks for your answer!